# Loss function for Image captioning with visual attention

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

I am trying to understand the TensorFlow implementation of Image captioning with visual attention. I understand what SparseCategoricalCrossentropy is but what is `loss_function` doing? Can someone explain? [Tensorflow Implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning#checkpoint)

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')

def loss_function(real, pred):
  mask = tf.math.logical_not(tf.math.equal(real, 0))
  loss_ = loss_object(real, pred)

  mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=loss_.dtype)
  loss_ *= mask

  return tf.reduce_mean(loss_)
```

Comment: please can i get your email ?

Comment: @user3188912 921yash@gmail.com

Comment: can you check it , please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to go back to what is in `real`. In `real` we have words encoded as `number` with `tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer`. In the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning#preprocess_and_tokenize_the_captions), the value 0 is for the `<pad>` token.

```
tokenizer.word_index['<pad>'] = 0
```

So, the loss function simply apply a mask to discard the predictions made on the `<pad>` tokens, because they don't provide meaningful information for the training of the network.